# use xuggler to play video on jpanel

Tags: java, swing, xuggler

I want to create a class extended jpanel.
that class must play an mp4 movie.
I use Xuggler to play it.
I create this class extends JFrame but i want help to put it in jpanel or Canvas or some thing that i can put it in jframe.

```
package pack;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaListenerAdapter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.event.IVideoPictureEvent;

public class VideoPlayer
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String sourceUrl = "D:\\DriSch\\Intro.MP4";

    VideoPlayer videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer();
    videoPlayer.play(sourceUrl);
  }

  public void play(String sourceUrl)
  {
    IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(sourceUrl);
    reader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

    final MyVideoFrame frame = new MyVideoFrame();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

    MediaListenerAdapter adapter = new MediaListenerAdapter()
    {
      @Override
      public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event)
      {
        frame.setImage((BufferedImage) event.getImage());
      }
    };
    reader.addListener(adapter);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    while (reader.readPacket() == null)
      do {} while(false);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  private class MyVideoFrame extends JFrame
  {
    Image image;

    public void setImage(final Image image)
    {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
      {
        public void run()
        {
          MyVideoFrame.this.image = image;
          repaint();
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void paint(Graphics g)
    {
      if (image != null)
      {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but it seemed so easy that I am worried I missed a requirement.

```
private static class MyVideoPanel extends JPanel {

    Image image;

    public void setImage(final Image image) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyVideoPanel.this.image = image;
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```